# wxPython: global hotkey loop toggle

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a hotkey toggle(f12) that will turn on a loop when pressed once then turn that loop off when pressed again. The loop is a mouse click every .5 seconds when toggled on. I found a recipe for a hot keys on the wxpython site and I can get the loop to turn on but can't figure a way to get it to turn off. I tried created a separate key to turn it off without success.
The mouse module simulates 1 left mouse click.

Here's my current code:

import wx, win32con, mouse

from time import sleep

class  Frameclass(wx.Frame):

```
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
            super(Frameclass, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(400, 200))
            self.Centre()
            self.Show()
            self.regHotKey()
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_HOTKEY, self.handleHotKey, id=self.hotKeyId)
            self.regHotKey2()
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_HOTKEY, self.handleHotKey2, id=self.hotKeyId2)
    def regHotKey(self):
            """
            This function registers the hotkey Alt+F12 with id=150
            """
            self.hotKeyId = 150
            self.RegisterHotKey(self.hotKeyId,win32con.MOD_ALT, win32con.VK_F12)#the key to watch for
           
            
    def handleHotKey(self, evt):
            loop=True
            print('clicks on')
            while loop==True:
            #simulated left mouse click
                 mouse.click()
                 sleep(0.50)
                 
                 x=self.regHotKey2()
                 print(x)
                 if x==False:
                         print('Did it work?')
                         break
            else:
                 pass
```

## ---------------------second keypress hotkey--------

```
    def regHotKey2(self):
            self.hotKeyId2 = 100
            self.RegisterHotKey(self.hotKeyId2,win32con.MOD_ALT, win32con.VK_F11)
                    
    def handleHotKey2(self, evt):
            return False
            loop=False
            print(loop)
```

if **name**=='**main**':

```
showytitleapp=wx.App()
#gotta have one of these in every wxpython program apparently
Frameclass(None, title='Rapid Clicks')
showytitleapp.MainLoop()
#infinite manloop for catching all the program's stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loop` variable is locally scoped inside of `handleHotKey`.  Because `regHotKey2` is bound to `handleHotKey2`, which is a different listener, the event it generates will never affect the loop within `handleHotKey`.  Besides that, the first line of `handleHotKey2` is a return value, which will quit the function before the following two lines are executed.

Out of curiousity, what output does `x=self.regHotKey2(); print(x)` produce?

Try defining your loop variable at the class level instead of the function level -

```
def __init__(self, parent, title):
    ... your original stuff ...
    self.clicker_loop = False
```

and then modifying *that* loop in your handlers -

```
def handleHotKey(self, evt):
    self.clicker_loop = True
    while self.clicker_loop:
        ... do the thing ...

def handleHotKey2(self, evt):
    self.clicker_loop = False
```

Please try this and tell me if this works.

And maybe this will toggle the loop from the same hotkey...

```
def handleHotKey(self, evt):
    if self.clicker_loop:
        self.clicker_loop = False
    else:
        self.clicker_loop = True
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It wasn't notifying me when I got answers for some reason. Anyway, I did figure it out eventually. In this case x=self.regHotKey2(); print(x) outputs 'None'. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, but in and of itself didn't work. Trying with a second hotkey didn't do anything and the gui would lock up while the loop was running. It seems like this particular case needed a separate thread for the loop. I don't really understand threads yet so I cobbled together part of your code with mine and came up with a solution.

Comment: @nonperson Awesome! and congratulations.  I *love* having my answer chosen, but it's perfectly acceptable (and helpful for the community) if you answer your own question with the solution that worked and then choose it.

Answer (score 1):

I added these modules to my import:

`subprocess,signal,sys`

under my class I added these

```
def init(self, parent, title):
    self.clicker_loop = False
    self.PID=1
```

def openClicker(self,event):
    self.PID=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "123.py"])
I had to import sys and add sys.executable to my popen otherwise i got an error everytime i tried to open another python program.

```
    def handleHotKey(self, evt):
        if self.clicker_loop:
            self.clicker_loop = False
            print(self.clicker_loop)
            self.PID.terminate()
        else:
            self.clicker_loop = True
            print(self.clicker_loop)
            self.openClicker(self)
```

I kill the called loop process with self.PID.terminate(), otherwise it opens the seperate 123.py loop file.

The seperate 123.py file contains this code:

```
import mouse
from time import sleep
```

while True:
    mouse.click()
    sleep(1)
What this basically does is call upon a separate python file with the subprocess module when the hotkey is pressed, then kills that process when the hotkey is pressed again. Thanks for the help.